# _crtlIsValidHeapPointer(block) when using filter() in pcl

Tags: c++, pointers, point-cloud-library, pcl

```
void filterPC(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud) {

    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> downsample;
    downsample.setInputCloud(cloud);
    downsample.setLeafSize(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
    downsample.setFilterFieldName("z");
    downsample.setFilterLimits(0, 1.4);
    downsample.filter(*cloud);
}
```

When executing this code I get the error mentioned in the title and I have no clue how to fix this. This came after upgrading from pcl 1.8.1 to pcl 1.12, before the upgrade everything was fine. I am fairly new to pcl and c++ and have no idea what to do about it. Can someone please help?

Comment: This may be a bug in your code. Also make sure you did a totally clean build so there is no chance that some part of your project was compiled with the 1.8.1 headers.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are no 1.8.1 headers (build the project with cmake and made sure everything is up to date). This is practically the only code I have to this function. Where would the bug be here?